# iOS 5 Google JSON - How to parse nested object?

Tags: iphone, ios, json, ios5

I Am trying to parse a Youtube playlist:

If my JSON is structured like:

```
{"apiVersion" .... 
"items":[{"id2":"some-id","title":"songtitle",
```

I am perfectly able to parse the title via:

```
// Fill array
NSArray *items = [json objectForKey:@"items"];

// Get item from tableData
NSDictionary *item = [tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
// Set text on textLabel
[[cell textLabel] setText:[item objectForKey:@"title"]];
```

But if the JSON is like:

```
{"apiVersion" .... 
"items":[{"id1": .... "video":{"id2":"some-id","title":"songtitle",
```

How can i reach the nested object title?

Just a simple thing, but i am banging my head on this for hours now. Gets frustrating, thanks for your suggestions!

[EDIT]
This is the full structure:

```
{
    "items":
    [
    {
    "video":
            {
                "title": "Number One",
                "description": "Description one"
            },    
            {
             "title": "Number two",
                "description": "Description two"
            },
            {
                "title": "Number three",
                "description": "Description three"
            }
    },
    {   
    "video":
            {
         "title": "Number One",
             "description": "Description one"
            },
            {
                "title": "Number two",
              "description": "Description two"
            },
            {
               "title": "Number three",
              "description": "Description three"
            }
    }

    ]
}
```

Comment: can you show your entire JSON , its a bit confusing this way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your json is not valid. All the `titles` should be in array right? So they have to  be  in [ ]. You can use for example the following site to "debug" your json:

http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Also, in iOS 5 you can use the new built-in JSON api. Here is a nice tutorial for that:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Nevertheless, here is how your json should look like I guess:

```
{
   "items":[
      {
         "video":[
            {
               "title":"Number One",
               "description":"Description one"
            },
            {
               "title":"Number two",
               "description":"Description two"
            },
            {
               "title":"Number three",
               "description":"Description three"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "video":[
            {
               "title":"Number One",
               "description":"Description one"
            },
            {
               "title":"Number two",
               "description":"Description two"
            },
            {
               "title":"Number three",
               "description":"Description three"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Good luck with your project ;)

Comment: Thanks! I did not invent it either :) Its' the standard jsonc the youtube API spits out for playlists (check a real world example here: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/6A94E7DAD57DE702?v=2&alt=jsonc ) Already started looking into rewriting things here and there.

Comment: @Martindem Ok :),  ... but still the JSON provided from YouTube is valid json. They have items as array and each object in the array is a dictionary. Your sample has it differently and not valid (in terms of json). Anyway, I hope the post helped you little. Once more, good luck ;)

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that my simplification is not valid *bows head* /dives straight back into the code

Answer (score 3):

Try This:

```
NSArray *items = [[json valueForkey:@"items"]valueForkey:"video"];
```

Comment: Nope, also no effect. Also had to add the @ before items and uppercase valueForKey.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *items = [json valueForkey:@"items"];
for(int i =0;i<[items count]; i++)
{
  NSMutableArray *arrtitle = [[[items objectAtIndex:i]valueForkey:@"Video"]copy];
  for(int j =0;j<[arrtitle count]; j++)
  {
    NSString *title = [[arrtitle objectAtIndex:j]valueForkey:@"title"];
  }
}
```

maybe it will help you.

Comment: Nope, to no avail, works on the first piece of json, but not on the second. Xcode Also reports that title is an unused variable. NSLog echoes null.

Comment: The reason might be at [ ]. I'm speculating that this `NSMutableArray *items = [json valueForkey:@"items"];` and this `NSMutableArray *arrtitle = [[[items objectAtIndex:i]valueForkey:@"Video"]copy];` are not doing the same thing. Since The second part does not contain **[ ]** . Simply it was not a nested JSON. You probably want a real parser for this. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: the json hierarchy is array> dictionary> dictionary. so we must haver count for dictionay key video. so we get more three dictionary.